# stripe payments without popup

Tags: php, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe on a Symfony2 project, and the only payment method I see on their documentation is the "Pay with card" button https://stripe.com/docs/checkout which creates an embedded popup on my project. But the problem is that I need the users to insert their credit card number on Stripe's website, just like Paypal does. Is there any payment method that Stripe provides, and get all the user's informations from a form that is on their website?

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for something that will redirect the user to a form on **stripe's** website? They don't have that.

Answer (score 4):

Stripe doesn't offer a redirection to its site to collect card details. ([source](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-my-customers-go-to-stripe-com-to-make-a-payment))

In most instances, buyers don't even know they're using Stripe to pay.

To collect card details and turn them into a token, you can either:

- use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), a premade form with some customization options, or
- make your own form using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).

If neither of these is an option for you, you can check the list of [Stripe third-party integrations](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations) to see if something fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible.

Stripe customers are now able to use Client-only Checkout feature which is currently in beta. Flow is the same as with PayPal - users will be redirected to Stripe-hosted checkout website.

[Directing customers to Stripe to make payments online](https://support.stripe.com/questions/directing-customers-to-stripe-to-make-payments-online)